# Haskell's type for Pairs

Tags: haskell, types, ghci

I'm trying to understand Haskell's type system. And I came along the following:

```
*Main> :t ("Hello", 4)
("Hello", 4) :: Num t => ([Char], t)

*Main> :t ("Hello", 'a')
("Hello", 'a') :: ([Char], Char)

*Main> :t ("Hello", True)
("Hello", True) :: ([Char], Bool)
```

Why is the type for `("Hello", 4)` not denoted like the others. I would have expected it to be `("Hello", 4) :: ([Char], Num)`

I already saw the `=>` before. What I am wondering, is why does it make this difference?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's because `Num` is not a type; it is a [typeclass](http://learnyouahaskell.com/types-and-typeclasses), and `Num t => someType` means that `t` is some arbitrary type that is an instance of the `Num` typeclass. To borrow some Java/C# terminology, you can think of `Num` as an interface, and `Num t => t` is a generic type with the constraint that `t` must implement the `Num` interface.

In general, you find the typeclass constraints on the left side of the `=>` arrow, and the type body on the right side. We could have multiple class constraints, for example `(Num a, Num b) => (a, b)`, which would denote the type of a tuple of two arbitrary numeric types. We can also have zero class constraints, in which case the `=>` is omitted.

In Haskell the numeric literals can represent any type that is an instance of `Num`. The literal `4` could denote a float or an integer, or (if you define some more exotic instances) even a function.

Answer (score 3):

Number literals are a special case, the `4` could be e.g. interpreted as an `Int` or as an `Integer`, and the compiler won't make that choice for you, but takes a kind of "least common denominator" in the form of the common typeclass `Num` (as the other answers already explain).

The additional point I try to make is if you are more specific at this point, the weirdness disappears:

```
-- specify Int explicitly 
*Main> :t ("Hello", 4 :: Int)
("Hello", 4 :: Int) :: ([Char], Int)

-- specify Integer explicitly 
*Main> :t ("Hello", 4 :: Integer)
("Hello", 4 :: Integer) :: ([Char], Integer)

-- use an Int result from an expression
*Main> :t ("Hello", length [1,2,3])
("Hello", length [1,2,3]) :: ([Char], Int)
```

Answer (score 2):

`Num` is a typeclass. Typeclasses are sort of (but not really) like OO interfaces. Different types implement the functions of the typeclass, allowing for polymorphism.

For example, there is a standard `Eq` class, which is defined as (you can get this in ghci with `:info Eq`)

```
class Eq a where
  (==) :: a -> a -> Bool
  (/=) :: a -> a -> Bool
```

This means that you can write functions like `isMember :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> Bool`. This function takes something of a type `a` that implements (has an instance for) `Eq` and a list of that same type, and returns a boolean. This generic type signature means that you can do

```
elem 'c' "abcd"
elem 4 [1,2,3]
```

and it will compile, but that you can't do

```
elem 'c' [1,2,3]
```

Now, back to your original question.
When you type a number in ghci, it tries to give that number the most general type it can. It doesn't know whether `5` is an `Int`, or an `Integer`, or even a `Double`. So, the literal has the type `(Num t) => t`, which means "this thing can have any type `t` than implements the `Num` typeclass).

Different expressions will give you more specific types. For example, `` 5 `div` 3 `` has type `(Integral a) => a`, since `div` is a method of the `Integral` class.

If you'd like to learn more about typeclasses, [this](http://learnyouahaskell.com/types-and-typeclasses) is a good link.